# Wrong encoding between Spring and PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I have a Spring Boot (version 1.3) Web application, all in UTF-8, and a PostgreSQL server with server encoding UTF-8 and client encoding WIN1252.

The problem is that when I save in the DB something with special characters manually, the encoding is right, but from JDBC the string is saved wrong.

In the same way, when I have a string saved with special characters and I make a SELECT query to read manually, the encoding is right, but from JDBC the string is read wrongly.

Dropping the database and creating again is not a choice for the moment, so I have been trying a lot of things with poor result. Is there any solution for me?

PD: I have put all these properties in my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding = UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.charset = UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled = true
spring.http.encoding.force = true
spring.mandatory-file-encoding = UTF-8
server.tomcat.uri-encoding = UTF-8
spring.messages.encoding = UTF-8
```

Comment: I think your property is incorrectly named. Try `spring.datasource.sqlScriptEncoding=UTF-8` instead of `spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding = UTF-8`

Comment: I'm using _Spring Boot 1.3_, I didn't say it sorry. The property is called as you said in _Spring Boot 1.2_ I think. [Application Properties 1.3.3](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry.

Comment: It works for me straight out of the box with the default Boot settings. I posted € over HTTP and it saved correctly in the db and returned € in the response. Which unicode chars are you trying?

Comment: I have just test it saving '€' character, and it has been encoded as 'Ç' character. Have you the same server and client encoding as me?

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. I use Spring Boot 1.5.9 and postgres 9.6, data.sql with inserts. Encoding on data.sql was UTF-8, but after start of application, in DB was special symbols instead russian letters.

```
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding= UTF-8
```

This property in application.properties has helped.

All properties responsible for DB:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:/PostgresDS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=my_scheme_name
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.show-sql = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding= UTF-8
```

Comment: It is deprecated https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.6.3/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.java#L511 and remove in Spring Boot 3.0.

Comment: @happy_marmoset it sounds great!

Answer (score 1):

Now the correct option is:

```
spring.sql.init.encoding = UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you define the datasource URL, try adding ?characterEncoding=UTF-8 to the end of the URL

Comment: I added it, but the problem continues :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was on JVM side.

After I added:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

as VM option - problem was resolved