# initializing postgreSQL db with data.sql -file and having utf-8 encoding work

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When initializing postgreSQL database via application.properties using the data.sql -file, the inserted data with chars (like Ä and ö) that require utf-8 encoding do not get correctly encoded in their respective fields.

So, I have in the application.properties file the following by which to populate the database
...

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.data=classpath:data.sql
```

...

Spring does the schema creation by:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

What else should I define to get those chars to encode utf-8 correctly.

In addition, in pgAdmin properties I can see that the database itself is utf-8 encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer by finding it from an other thread: [Wrong encoding between Spring and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222213/wrong-encoding-between-spring-and-postgresql?rq=1).

This simply was needed in addition in application properties and utf-8 encoding now works:

```
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding= UTF-8
```